# Integrating ROS packages through PLC motor drivers

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a robot that is already programmed with PLC beckhoff through twinCAT to give commands to the motors to move at a certain speed and direction. I want to control my robot through ROS to do more interesting things like navigation, SLAM ... but i want to keep the PLC as a driver for the motors used and use the same old code to drive the motors with the same logic. Is there a way to integrate between ROS and PLC in such a way for example sending velocity commands (/cmd_vel) and the PLC drives the motors to the desired goal? Thank you in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229341/integrating-ros-packages-through-plc-motor-drivers/) by [wassimhariri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26309/wassimhariri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2016-03-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Balaji](https://answers.ros.org/users/26502/balaji/) on 2016-04-06**:
I am using Beckhoff PLC. How can i interface and program it. I have support for downloading.

**Comment by [sonyccd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25477/sonyccd/) on 2016-04-06**:
See my answer above I added link to my driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes amusing you can use modbus. I am doing the same thing myself.  I am almost done with a modbus driver for ros that runs over serial and Ethernet.  You can simply have ROS read a register and write to one to set the velocity.  I am using the Precision 2000 PLC from automation direct and have gotten a refresh rate of 20 registers at around 50Hz over Ethernet.  Look out on my github in the next few weeks for me to publish it.
https://github.com/sonyccd

Update:
I finished the PLC driver you can download it from here.
https://github.com/sonyccd/ros_plc_modbus

---

Originally posted by [sonyccd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25477/sonyccd/) with karma: 58 on 2016-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1